# New txt file not being created

Tags: java, printwriter

I am working on a settings file that will be created if none exists. I have tried creating a File instead but it didn't work either. The following code is used to create a new txt file.

```
            try {
            PrintWriter SettFile = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Settings.txt")));
            SettFile.println("170 000 150");
            SettFile.println("114 000 106");
            SettFile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error Accured Loading The Settings");
        }
        System.out.println("Setting File Succesfuly Created");
```

The following code is used to search for the values.

```
        try{
        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("Settings")));
        System.out.println("Reading Values from \"Settings.txt\"...");
        int i = 0;
        String TempSettingValue;

        while((TempSettingValue = file.readLine()) != null){
            SettingValue[i] = TempSettingValue;
            System.out.println("Value " + (i + 1) + ": " + SettingValue[i]);
            i++;
        }

        file.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Something went wrong loading the Settings...");
    }
```

Comment: What happens that makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't show up in the file system, and the program says it can't load settings later on

Comment: @F.johansson Running this code I did not get any errors and the file was created with the contents that you put into it!

Comment: @F.johansson can you post the code that it looking for the file? I think you are just looking in the wrong location!

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for file in correct place?

Comment: Might it have to do with how I have setup the filesystem for the program?

Comment: @F.johansson Search for the created file in your project root directory.

Comment: Didn't find it in the project root directory.

Comment: @F.johansson Post your code that looks for your settings file!

Comment: I have sorted my classes into different packages. Might this cause the problem?

Comment: When you create this file it is being created inside your project folder, its being created with the src folder. So if you are looking for it inside your source or res folder then you arent going to find it. You're going to need to define a path to the folder where you want it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

The problem is that you are looking for "Settings"

```
 BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("Settings")));
```

Change that line to this.

```
 BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("Settings.txt")));
```